# Pages on third level not showing in menu

Tags: powerapps

In my powerpages "pages" section I have added a submenu A under HOME, the under A I added a subpage B and these two levels are showing nicely in the menu as expected but if I under B add a new page C this page is not showed in the menu but I can navigate it to using the URL directly.

How can I make page C show up in my menu as a submenu of B?